# Pad currency to fixed width (ToString("C")) with zeros?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency

So I am curious if its possible for me to use the `.ToString("C")` method to generate a currency value off of my number, but have it display the value combined with a minimum value.

An example, lets say that my number would never ever go above $1,000.00. However, the values that are usually generated are below like this, $0,487.00. I know your probably thinking why would you want to do that. In this situation I don't want the label size to increase or decrease based on the content. Also, I want the numbers to be substituted with 0's if they are not filled in by the actual dollar amount. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the label be made fixed-width?

Comment: You mean, if there is currency 487, you want to show it like $0,487.00 ? Or 45, like $0,045.00 ? If so, you can use a custom currency format with using String.Format("${0:0,000.00}", yourValue);

Comment: Yes, I guess my main concern was the content. I don't want the content to be re sizing. I am going for a centered fixed content approach. I will edit my question

Comment: @MitjaBonca Yes on both questions, I believe they are the same if I am reading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a custom format string:

```
.ToString("$0,000.00");
```

Note that by using `0`s instead of `#`s in your format string, it guarantees that those digits will be present, even if the number's not big enough.

Comment: This will work perfectly! Just tested it. @Tony Leeper sorry he had like 5 seconds on you :(

Comment: Good to know. Note that if you're worried about the appearance in different countries, you will have to look at the [RegionInfo.CurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, as well as the appropriate properties for thousand seperators and decimal places. Different regions also put the currency symbol on different ends of the number.

Comment: You also aren't handling negative values the same way as the "C" format string, if memory serves.

Comment: If you're worried about wanting to format negative values differently, just use the section seperator: `.ToString("$0,000.00;($0,000.00)");`

Comment: If you're worried about wanting to format zero values differently, you can use another: `.ToString("$0,000.00;($0,000.00);'BROKE'");`

Comment: The point is that none of the issues brought up in the comments are in the answer...They're all solveable, you just haven't shown the solution

Comment: I don't want to complicate a simple answer to a simple question. If the user wants to know the answers to a bunch of questions he didn't ask, he can see them in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
.ToString("$0,000.00")
```

Comment: Won't this break in different locales?